# Xamarin Xaml Styles for background in ContentPage

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Newly working in Xamarin and it appears that if I try to set a style for `ContentPage` nothing happens

Xaml in App.xaml's ResourceDictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPage">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#f8f8f8"/>
</Style>
```

I know that the app.xaml style is being read.  I have a button style that has been applied globally.  But I cannot seem to affect any change on `ContentPage`.  No errors are being reported.

How can I globally set the backgroundcolor?

I've read that this might be a bug, but that was a year ago.  If it is still a bug is there a workaround?

Comment: Please read this post, it could be usefull, there is a bug related to this and some workaround too https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34798/how-to-add-global-background-color-style

Comment: I've tried this, but am having a hard time then figuring out what the xaml in my main page would look like

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk, thanks for the help.  You pointed me to the right path.

Comment: super so maybe vote up for my comment? ;)

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk, I'll go one better as comment upvotes do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the tip by @Tomasz Kowalczyk using the example xaml [from this rather incomplete post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34798/how-to-add-global-background-color-style):

In app.xaml ResourceDictionary put this style:

```
<Style x:Key="defaultPageStyle" TargetType="ContentPage">
   <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#f8f8f8"/>
</Style>
```

The base class is called `BaseContentPage`

```
public class BaseContentPage : ContentPage
{
    public BaseContentPage()
    {
        var style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["defaultPageStyle"];
        Style = style;
    }
}
```

Then to tie it all together in each xaml.cs class:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MyXamlPage: BaseContentPage
```

And .xaml file

```
<local:BaseContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyNamespace"
         x:Class="MyNamespace.MyXamlPage"
```

Comment: What would that look like in C#?

Comment: @tmighty, i dont understand.  This solution is in both c# and xaml.

Comment: Shouldn't the constructor of BaseContentPage make a call to InitializeComponent(); ?

Answer (score 7):

Following code in `App.xaml` works for me:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPage" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
   <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Lime" />
</Style>
```

Note:

- You should NOT use attribute `x:Key` in `Style`.
- You should add `ApplyToDerivedTypes="True"`

I found solution at https://putridparrot.com/blog/styles-in-xamarin-forms/